# TYPO3 backend Icon with iconidentifier for custom content element

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I registered my icons in `ext_localconf.php` like this:

```
<?php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry;
$extKey = 'xxx';
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry $iconRegistry */
    $iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconRegistry::class);
    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        'xxx_intro-icon-identifier',

        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Public/icons/baseline-web_asset-24px.svg']
    );
```

I want to use the **iconidentifier** in tt_content.php with `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin()` to set the icon for the drop-down menu. Who do I achieve this?

Comment: Put your this code in tt_content.php
It will work but due to cashing issue it will disapear
    $iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconRegistry::class);
    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        'xxx_intro-icon-identifier',

        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Public/icons/baseline-web_asset-24px.svg']
    );

Answer (score 0):

I know this solution:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    [
        'LLL:EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:your_ctype.title',
        'your_ctype',
        'your_icon_identifier'
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);
```

Place this snippet in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`